# Is Cloud Service on Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have deployed a cloud service (classic) to an Azure Virtual Network (classic), using this config:

```
 <NetworkConfiguration>
   <VirtualNetworkSite name="Group Group test" />
     <AddressAssignments>
        <InstanceAddress roleName="webrole1">
           <Subnets><Subnet name="webroles" /></Subnets>
        </InstanceAddress>
        <InstanceAddress roleName="webrole2">
           <Subnets><Subnet name="webroles" /></Subnets>
        </InstanceAddress>
        <InstanceAddress roleName="workerrole">
           <Subnets><Subnet name="workerroles" /></Subnets>
        </InstanceAddress>
```

The roles are up and running, but they are not appearing under 'Resources in this subnet' in the portal. It therefore looks like the roles haven't been deployed to the virtual network. Are there any powershell commands I can run to list resources deployed to a virtual network, or list subnets connected to a cloud service?

Comment: usually this is the case. The easiest way to tell is to check the private IP addresses of your role instances. Also make sure you have enough capacity in your sub-nets. You can try the following powershell to get details:
Get-AzureRole -ServiceName "MySvc01" -Slot "Production" -InstanceDetails

Comment: Thanks very much! The private IP addresses do match up, so it looks like the deployment did work. It's so confusing that they don't appear in the UI though, as the VMs I've added to the network do show up.